# React Native Deep Linking and fallback to webpage by passing some data

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I have a website (implemented with React) and a React-native app to use camera and process some data.

In my scenario, on the website, there is a button to open the camera by deep-linking to my React-native app which I've already done. When the user clicks the button on the website in his/her phone, the react-native app is opened. This part is already implemented.

After taking a photo and processing it in the app, I want a clean fallback to the website with the processed data to represent it on the website.

The first solution that came to my mind is that maybe I could save the processed data to a JSON file in a certain directory on the phone and exit the app using "react-native-exit-app". After exiting the app, the browser will appear again and I can read the JSON file on the website. But I am not sure if it is a good approach.

So In other words, I just want to pass the processed data to website after exiting the app. What would be the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way in my opinion would be:

1. User Lands on website then taps camera.
2. User is universal linked through to RN app
3. user takes a picture
4. Call an API (that you will have to build) to store the image on your server and store a reference in a database
5. Use RN linking `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#openurl` to open a page that will serve the user back the image you stored in your database

You could also skip the api part and let them take a picture then base64 encode it and then call a website url that takes a base64 image as a param and coverts it. A little like this site: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter but not sure if a base 64 image would break the url character limit